# Does Ted Chiang's Omphalos hide a second, less obvious meaning?

Tags: short-stories, ted-chiang

This is my first question and I must admit I haven't put much effort in making sure it is on-topic for the community, but I felt this was the right place to ask.

I've read about the 2019 short story by Ted Chiang, [Omphalos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_(story)).

*(Note: The post was edited out, upon a suggestion, regarding the apparent lack of receptiveness towards the story, which had been considered undeserved, by at least [one](https://camestrosfelapton.wordpress.com/2020/05/13/hugo-novelette-omphalos-ted-chiang/) reviewer which I've kept cited for completeness)*

You could look at it from the Omphalos hypothesis POV (referenced in the linked Wikipedia article) which may not make it particularly appealing but you could also look at it as an analogy to

> the global power shift from the Western Culture/Civilization (represented basically by USA/Europe) to the East (China/Russia but specially China) in which the Western Civilization initially established itself as the "center of the world" with a number of achievements, but could ultimately fail to assure its dominance and prevent the subversion of its own values by the East, implying in a future dominance by the latter.

**Story spoilers ahead**

> In the story, the world was demonstrably created by God and this is confirmed by science, along with the belief that the planet where the protagonist lives is the center of the Universe. Then she finds out that this belief is only partially true; indeed the Universe has a center, but it lies within a different planet. The world wasn't created for her people after all. The bottom line seems to be that "people will resist it but eventually learn to live along with this new notion" and that the whole notion and the advancements that allowed to attain that knowledge are pointless.

> That seems to be in agreement with what I mentioned before. Science, democracy, capitalism, Chistianity and other Western Civilization staples won't be enough to prevent the center of the world from shifting to its real center. They actually just serve to help accomplish exactly that. The East learns how to play along with those values (in the context of a long-term global domination plan) without losing its distinct culture and essence, and manages to subvert them in order to reach dominance. The current power holders will have to learn to live with the new establishment, and will eventually do exactly that. Probably in a government/governments with massive China-provided AI surveillance as many technologists predict -- I couldn't find the predictions collection I've read once but [this one article I found](https://emerj.com/ethics-and-regulatory/artificial-intelligence-government-surveillance/) fits the bill -- and other totalitarist nightmares. Also, please consider the author's Eastern origin in that interpretation.

In that sense I think it is a frighteningly spot-on story/analogy/omen.

Does the story actually try to say that or point that out (along with a less stretchy interpretation)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I could be wrong, but I suspect this might be one of those questions that gets closed on the basis that the answers are likely to be based purely on speculation, rather than evidence. As a general rule, answers that aren't based at least partly on evidence are frowned upon here, and questions which appear to invite such answers are frowned upon also. That said, I didn't click to view any of your spoilers, so I could be overlooking some relevant information. We'll have to wait and see how other users feel about this question.

Comment: @user14111 I see, thanks for pointing that out. I've added a link in the question to one such a review which I remember having read.

Comment: @LogicDictates I see. Thank you for let me know. If at the very least a portion of the Sci-Fi community exposed to my silly theory finds it interesting thoughtfood, I'll feel rewarded.

Comment: A few small edits would make your question much more objective and much less likely to be closed. 1) Edit out the question of whether it deserves praise. That is too subjective. 2) Change it from "can it be interpreted this way" (the answer to any such question is yes, if you want to, you can interpret it however you like) to "Is this what the story is saying?" (more answerable). Obviously, it is your choice whether to make these edits, but the question is on the border of being too subjective for the site.

Comment: As for me, with such an obvious religious interpretation that fits with the story, and Ted Chiang's history of writing stories with quirky takes on religious ideas, I would find it kind of reaching to make it about Earth geopolitics. Also, I do not know whether Chang considers democracy, capitalism, and science to be "European" in nature, but do note that precursors to democracy are found throughout the world, and China was a pioneer in scientific research for millenia. As far as capitalism, we are talking about the country that invented paper money.

Comment: @Adamant Thanks, I've edited the question. You make good points, particularly since I'm not familiar with Ted Chiang's work. I guess I was a bit pretentious to think others hadn't yet figured out a potential second meaning to the story. It's just that it fitted so well within my (not-so-accurate) geopolitics assumptions. Anyway, I'm thankful for having been able to discuss that here.